# Action Mailer configuration difficulties with sendGrid

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, sendgrid

I have a rails [web application](https://gastromend.herokuapp.com) under construction with a form done in pure HTML.

I am having difficulty wiring the form up so that the application emails me the submitted fields using `Sendgrid`.

When I hit the submit button on the form I am getting No route matches [POST] "/"

I have followed this [tutorial](https://matharvard.ca/posts/2014/dec/31/contact-form-in-rails-4/) and implemented the instructions in chronological order, yet I am still having bother. Any steering or help with the code would be appreciated.

config/environments/production.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_startstls_auto => true
  }
```

index.html.erb

```
<form  method="post" name="frmContentDownload"><!-- /. form handling starts here-->

      <div>
        <label for="FirstName1">First Name</label><input class="form-control" name="FirstName1" type="text" value="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="LastName1">Last Name</label><input class="form-control" name="LastName1" type="text" value="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email</label><input class="form-control" name="emailAddress" type="text" value="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone</label><input class="form-control" name="PhoneNumber" type="text" value="" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="Title1">Title</label><input class="form-control" name="Title1" type="text" value="" />
      </div>


      <!-- /. this is the drop down box for the states-->

      <div><label for="StateProvince1">State or Province</label><select class="form-control" name="StateProvince1">
        <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>COUNTRY &#8609;</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
      </select></div>

        <div>
          <label for="comments">Comments</label><input class="form-control" name="comments" type="text" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Contact Us" />
        </div>

</form>
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord

    include ActiveModel::Model
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :FirstName1, :LastName1, :emailAddress, :PhoneNumber, :Title1, :StateProvince1, :comments

    validates :FirstName1,
       presence: true

    validates :LastName1,
       presence: true


    validates :emailAddress,
       presence: true


    validates :PhoneNumber,
       presence: true


    validates :Title1,
       presence: true


    validates :StateProvince1,
       presence: true


    validates :comments,
       presence: true

end
```

the mailer class

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'notifications@example.com'
    default to: 'chrisdorman1978@gmail.com'

    def welcome_email(user)
        @user = user
        @url = 'http://example.com/login'
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Thank you for the enquiry, Gastromend will be in touch')
    end

    def new_message(message)
        @message = message

        mail subject: "Message from #{message.name}"
    end 

end
```

controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


    def new
       @message = Message.new
    end


    def create
       @message = Message.new(message_params)

       if @message.valid?
         ContactMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
         redirect_to contact_path, notice: "Your messages has been sent."
       else
         flash[:alert] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
         render :new
       end
    end 


    private

    def message_params
       params.require(:message).permit(:FirstName1, :LastName1, :emailAddress, :PhoneNumber, :Title1, :StateProvince1, :comments)
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root :to => "pages#index"   
  get 'pages/index'

  get 'contact', to: 'messages#new', as: 'contact'
  post 'contact', to: 'messages#create'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

new_message.text.erb

```
<%= @message.name %> <<%= @message.email %>> wrote:


<%= @message.content %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, if you type `rake routes` on your console then it showing

```
contact GET    /contact(.:format)          messages#new
        POST   /contact(.:format)          messages#create
```

That means your post action URL is `/contact` then your `form` tag will be

```
<form action="/contact" method="post" name="frmContentDownload">
```

**Additionally written for you based on [rails form helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)**

Why you not using `Rails` form tag, see if you use this with **Rails** form tag then it will be like this

```
<%= form_tag mail_send_path, method: :post do %>
      <div>
        <label for="FirstName1">First Name</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :FirstName1, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First Name" %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="LastName1">Last Name</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :LastName1, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
        <%= email_field :emailAddress, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :PhoneNumber, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "PhoneNumber" %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="Title1">Title</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :Title1, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Title1" %>
      </div>


      <!-- /. this is the drop down box for the states-->

      <div><label for="StateProvince1">State or Province</label>
        <%= select_tag(:StateProvince1, '<option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="UK">United Kingdom</option><option value="US">United States</option>') %>
      </div>

        <div>
          <label for="comments">Comments</label>
          <%= text_field_tag :comments, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "comments" %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Contact Us" />
        </div>
<% end %>
```

and your routes file will be like this

get 'contact', to: 'messages#new', as: 'contact'
  post 'contact', to: 'messages#create', as: 'mail_send'

then now if you will run `rake routes` then it will be shown like this

```
contact GET    /contact(.:format)          messages#new
mail_send POST   /contact(.:format)          messages#create
```

Now `mail_send` is your form post request path

Comment: when I submit the form I get a screen saying "the change you wanted was rejected" any ideas?

Comment: error, to be honest im thinking of doing this in php, in 1 file rather that 10